# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**While attemping to create two objects (without nested serializer)from one end point. i got an error
ERROR:
 AttributeError at /migratestudent
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `registration_no` on serializer `StudentDataMigrateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Student` instance.
Original exception text was: `'Student' object has no attribute 'registration_no'`.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sex  = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES,max_length=255, null=True)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Registration(models.Model):
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, 
    on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='registration')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.registration_no

class StudentDataMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField()
    sex = serializers.CharField()
    registration_no = serializers.CharField()
    #registration_no = serializers.CharField()


    def create(self,validated_data):
        name = validated_data.pop('name')
        sex = validated_data.pop('sex')
        registration_no= validated_data.pop('registration_no')
        #registration_no = validated_data.pop('registration_no')
        #check for existence of registration number

        #Student.objects.CheckRegistration(name, '4')

        try:
            regn = Registration.objects.get('registration_no')
        except:
            student = Student.objects.create(name=name, sex=sex)
            registration = Registration.objects.create(
                    registration_no=registration_no,
                    student=student)

        return student

class StudentDataMigrateCreateAPIVIew(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class= StudentDataMigrateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        student = Student.objects.all()
        return student
```

Answer (score 6):

You are defining these fields on your serializer:

```
class StudentDataMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    sex = serializers.CharField()
    registration_no = serializers.CharField()
```

And returning `student` object in your `create` method:

```
    def create(self,validated_data):
        ...
        return student
```

When you make a post request to this endpoint, `StudentDataMigrateCreateAPIVIew` is creating the serializer (`StudentDataMigrateSerializer`) using request data and validating it. If the validation passes, it calls `create` method of serializer. Everything is okay until now. After creating the instance, the view also must return a response. So it returns `data` attribute of serializer.

At this point, `serializer.data` is actually representation of the student object you returned in your `create` method. Your serializer tries to return a representation based on the fields defined in it.

These are your defined fields on serialize: `name`, `sex`, `registration_no`. But `Student` model, hence `student` object has no `registration_no` field. So your serializer fails when it tries to get this field on `student` object.

You can make `registration_no` field `write_only` so that it wont be returned in response.

```
class StudentDataMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    sex = serializers.CharField()
    registration_no = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: thank you. it works. How about if i want to returned registration_no

Comment: Then you should [override `to_representation` method of serializer.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)